# WebSphere on AIX not taking system time

Tags: aix, websphere-8

I have WebSphere 8 running on AIX and am currently experimenting with date simulation. For this purpose I use a software package called Time Machine from SolutionSoft.

The idea with Time Machine is that it replaces the system time API so that a user can specify any date, a frozen date and even the cadence.

Now, this is all very well and AIX and for instance date and "touch -m" both work as expected. When it comes to WAS8 there is quite a different story.

From what I can tell keeps WAS picking up the real time and not the system time, and this is a bother as you can realise. I have not found a way to make WAS aware of the simulated time - I have tried restarting the WAS-processes to no avail.

Anybody know how the combination WAS/AIX is handling time and, more specifically, how I can persuade WAS to pick up the simulated time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to first make Time Machine aware of the JRE that comes with WAS as this is not done automatically. This is done with the tminstall command:

```
tminstall -j <path to JVM directory>
```

Once done, it is possible to manipulate the WAS time using the tmuser command. For example

```
tmuser -a -u wasuser -x 122323592015
```

to set the time to almost midnight, the night before Christmas 2015.